# Javascript. Как передать аргументом в функцию css selector?

Tags: javascript

```
function changeCss(node, selector, property){
   node.style.ВОТ СЮДА = property;
}
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос не очень понятен. Расскажите подробнее, что нужно сделать.

Comment: В функцие changeCss после .style вставить аргументом например backgroundImage или margin

Comment: @DenisoDeniso А у вас разве вопрос не про селекторы?

Comment: Какую роль играет аргумент `node`?

Comment: Аргумент node - в моем случае h3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишем функцию `changeCss`, которая принимает селектор `selector`, свойство CSS `property` и значение для этого свойства `value`:

```
function changeCss(selector, property, value) {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
        nodes[i].style[property] = value;
    }
}
```

Примеры вызовов

```js
function changeCss(selector, property, value) {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
        nodes[i].style[property] = value;
    }
}

changeCss("#img", "width", "200px");
changeCss("#img", "height", "200px");
changeCss("#img", "background-image", "url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-6.jpg)");
changeCss(".text", "margin", "10px");
changeCss(".text", "color", "red");
changeCss(".text", "font-size", "50px");
```

```html
<div id="img">
</div>

<div class="text">
  This is text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию `eval`, которая превращает строку в код:

```
function changeCss(node, selector, property) {
   eval(node+'.style.'+selector+' = "'+property+'"');
};
```

```js
function changeCss(node, selector, property) {
   eval(node+'.style.'+selector+' = "'+property+'"');
};
$(function() {
  changeCss('document.getElementById("text")', 'color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="text">Текст</div>
```

Comment: Ох и шалун. С `eval` нужно быть осторожным, потому что можно получить что угодно здесь.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, да, я такой :D Это первое, что пришло в голову